# Parsing text using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

guys i am stuck while parsing following text into object. I have created two separate regex but i want to make only one. Below i am posting sample text as well as my following regex pattern.

```
PAYER:\r\n\r\n   MCNA \r\n\r\nPROVIDER:\r\n\r\n   MY KHAN \r\n   Provider ID: 115446397114\r\n   Tax ID: 27222193992\r\n\r\nINSURED:\r\n\r\n   VICTORY OKOYO\r\n   Member ID: 60451158048\r\n   Birth Date: 05/04/2008\r\n   Gender: Male\r\n\r\nCOVERAGE TYPE:\r\n\r\n   Dental Care
```

REGEX:

```
 re = new RegExp('(.*?):\r\n\r\n(.*?)(?:\r\n|$)', 'g');
re2 = new RegExp('(.*?):(.*?)(?:\r\n|$)', 'g');
```

Expected result:

```
{
  payer: 'MCNA',
  provider: 'MY KHAN'
}
```

Comment: What is the result you're trying to achieve? Could it be possible to simplify the input used in your question?

Comment: i want object like this => { payer: 'MCNA', provider: 'MY KHAN'};

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal That belongs in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @I0_ol what do you mean by 'belongs in the question'?

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the right tool here. At least not entirely. Maybe you could split on new lines and iterate through the result of that to create your object?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal I mean the desired output. You should edit the question to make it clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @I0_ol i already checked by splitting off the lines

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Showing people what you've tried is going to be a lot more helpful than just telling them. "I already checked by splitting off the lines" doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: @I0_ol you are right but can you tell me where to edit the question?

Comment: Maybe try clicking the "Edit" button underneath the question ;)

Comment: I believe you are trying to remove carriage letter and new line char. and then form the string as json?

Comment: @sal yes you pointed out right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns your input into an object that contains all key/value pairs:

```js
const input = 'PAYER:\r\n\r\n   MCNA \r\n\r\nPROVIDER:\r\n\r\n   MY KHAN \r\n   Provider ID: 115446397114\r\n   Tax ID: 27222193992\r\n\r\nINSURED:\r\n\r\n   VICTORY OKO\r\n   Member ID: 60451158048\r\n   Birth Date: 05/04/2009\r\n   Gender: Male\r\n\r\nCOVERAGE TYPE:\r\n\r\n   Dental Care';

let result = Object.fromEntries(input
  .replace(/([^:]+):\s+([^\n\r]+)\s*/g, (m, c1, c2) => c1.toLowerCase() + '\r' + c2 + '\n')
  .split('\n')
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(item => item.trim().split('\r'))
);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  "payer": "MCNA",
  "provider": "MY KHAN",
  "provider id": "115446397114",
  "tax id": "27222193992",
  "insured": "VICTORY OKO",
  "member id": "60451158048",
  "birth date": "05/04/2009",
  "gender": "Male",
  "coverage type": "Dental Care"
}
```

Explanation:

- `Object.fromEntries()` -- convert a 2D array to object, ex: `[ ['a', 1], ['b', 2] ]` => `{a: 1, b: 2}`
- `.replace()` regex `/([^:]+):\s+([^\n\r]+)\s*/g` -- two capture groups, one for key, one for value
- replace action `c1.toLowerCase() + '\r' + c2 + '\n'` -- convert key to lowercase, separate key/value pairs with newline
- `.split('\n')` -- split by newline
- `.filter(Boolean)`: -- remove empty items
- `.map(item => item.trim().split('\r'))` -- change array item to [key, value], e.g. change flat array to 2D array

You could add one more filter after the `.map()` to keep only keys of interest.

Comment: Hello peter thanks for helping out but i need one more thing. Following i am posting little bit of change structure

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal: I believe I answered your original question, let me know if not. The example input in your new question is more complex, it's unlikely that it can be done in one regex.  The first one with address that spans multiple lines possibly can, but `COVERAGE DATES: Plan Date: 05/01/2022 - 02/28/2223` has two consecutive keys, thus is non-deterministic and needs clarification.

Comment: you answered my original question without a doubt.